# Optimise usability of wgrep

Tags: emacs, grep

I'm using `wgrep` quite often for refactoring and generally it performs quite well. However, there are some minor annoyances which I hope can be resolved:

1. After doing an `rgrep` search, changing to `wgrep` and performing the changes in the `rgrep` buffer, `wgrep` will open all files that are to be changed and executes the modifications. However, when doing so, the files are opened normally in emacs, thus they will undergo the normal mode-loading stuff, which can take quite some time if this action involves large source files which are parsed.

   > Is it possible modify *wgrep* such that it opens the files in the most basic mode (I guess *fundamental-mode*  <s>*normal-mode*</s>) instead?
2. After executing the changes, `wgrep` will not close any newly opened buffers.

   > Is it possible to change *wgrep* such that it will automatically close any buffers that were opened during the execution phase (i.e. buffers which were not opened before the *wgrep* procedure started).

Finally, the *meta* question: Is this rather an *issue* to be posted to the issue tracker of the [wgrep developer](https://github.com/mhayashi1120/Emacs-wgrep) or is it a proper StackOverflow question?

Comment: Regarding the "meta" question: posting here may help other people to find answers and/or learn about useful stuff.  Using developer and/or issue tracker is imho ok if this is an issue or featured request (you investigated and there is no way to do what you want).  StackOverflow may help with this investigation to some users.

Comment: FYI, `normal-mode` is the function which determines the appropriate major mode to use, calls that, and then sets up all the file & directory-local variables (all the stuff you're seeking to avoid, in other words). `fundamental-mode` is what you were wanting.

Comment: @phils -- It's not just `fundamental-mode` that is needed, if you want to avoid the usual file-visiting overhead: You also want to avoid processing hooks and file-local variables.  There is a fair amount of fiddling to do and care to take.  And then, if you do want to actually visit some of the files, you need to take care to invoke all of that stuff properly (else kill the buffer and then just visit it properly).  See `icicle-find-file-of-content-action-1` and `icicle-find-file-of-content-1`, in `icicles-cmd1.el`, for an example of such code.

Comment: @phils Thanks for letting me know. That makes automatic identification of code snippets even more specific!

Answer (score 3):

From what I see in the wgrep.el source, you would need to modify (or aggressively `defadvice`) some functions of wgrep.el.

In particular, in `wgrep-get-file-buffer` the RAWFILE argument of `find-file-noselect` should be t, in your case, and the buffer should be added to a list of buffers to kill.  In `wgrep-finish-edit` a `dolist` on that new list could be used to kill the buffers wgrep opened.

So a feature request to the author could be in order :-)

In the meantime, the changes you need are easy to implement (just override the short `wgrep-get-file-buffer` and "defadvice after" `wgrep-finish-edit`), but you would be vulnerable to upgrades on the package.

[ And of course a patch/pull request could be sent to the author, but in that case maybe a new configuration variable should be added (`wgrep-auto-kill-buffer` or something like that) ]